# how to increment date by 1. input is string type having date as a value

Tags: groovy

I have to develop a custom groovy code to take string as input, it would be a date. Increase the date by one, then return it. As the input is a string I would need help to handle this.
thanks in advance for the help.
for example.
Input to the script - 05/12/2021
Output - 06/12/2021

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Groovy way to do it:

```
def input = '05/12/2021'
def today = Date.parse('dd/MM/yyyy', input)
def tomorrow = today.plus(1)
assert tomorrow.format('dd/MM/yyyy') == '06/12/2021'
```

You can do all of that in one line too:

```
Date.parse('dd/MM/yyyy', '05/12/2021').plus(1).format('dd/MM/yyyy')
```

Comment: FYI... Instead of `today.plus(1)` Groovy allows you to do `today + 1`.

Comment: Yip. Trying to be as explanatory as possible in my answers.

Comment: my code : 
def today = Date.parse('MM/dd/yyyy', var1[i])
def tomorrow = today.plus(1)
assert tomorrow.format('MM/dd/yyyy')
output.addValue(tomorrow);


input     06/29/2021
out put   Wed Jun 30 00:00:00 UTC 2021  Increment is happening, however format is invalid. how to get it in MM/dd/yyyy format ?

Comment: Don't use the assert, it was just to illustrate the result. If you keep it in, the assert has to have `== ' 06/29/2021'` in, else the code will stop execution.

Comment: def today = Date.parse('MM/dd/yyyy', var1[i])                                                                             input is 06/29/2021. if I print the value of today it would be Wed Jun 29 00:00:00 UTC 2021. i think some how this Date.parse not working. why ? do I need to import any packages into my code ?

Comment: No you shouldn't have to. Check your datatypes with `.getClass()` is all I can think of. The `var1[i]` should be a string and `.format()` should return a string.

Comment: `def TerminationDate = var1[i]            
def nextDate = Date.parse('MM/dd/yyyy', TerminationDate).plus(1).format('MM/dd/yyyy')`
One line  code worked for me. it gives correct result and format.  Thanks for sharing this code. I am still curious to make that multiple lines of code to work.

Comment: "Trying to be as explanatory as possible in my answers." - Understood.  Use of the `+` operator is idiomatic.

Comment: @jeff-scott-brown noted.

Comment: @jeff-scott-brown do you perhaps have a link explaining how this is idiomatic? I looked at https://groovy-lang.org/styleguide.html but couldn't link this to an example there. Genuinely interested.

Comment: @ou_ryperd There is information about operator overloading at https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html.